bug on browser on popstate
There is a link on my site that when I click on it, opens a page and then a popup opens.
The browser history saves 3 states

The initial page of the site - myproject.com/
The page we clicked on - myproject.com/page
The state of the page with an open popup - myproject.com/page#popup

Google Chrome:
When the popup is open, after pressing the "back" button, I am redirected to the myproject.com/ page (after 2 pages of history)
Mozilla Firefox
When the popup is open, after pressing the "back" button, I only close the popup
What could this be related to? Can this be fixed?
$(window).on('popstate') not working
